# jquery jtable sorting does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I am using jquery jtable. But my sorting does not work. I want to sort based on myPoolName column. I have added the sorting:true. But it does not work. Please help.

Following is the code.

```
  j('#infoTableId').jtable({

        paging : true, //Enable paging
        pageSize : 10, //Set page size (default: 10)   
        cache: false,
        sorting:true,
        actions : {

             listAction: '${baseURL}/myListPaginationDataTablesAjaxCall.html'

        },
   recordsLoaded: function(event, data) {
        buildPendCodesDropDown();
     },
         fields: {     

                MyId : {
                            title : 'My Id',
                            width : '15%',
                            key : true,
                            list : true,
                            edit : false,
                            create : false
                        },
                myPoolName : {
                            title : 'My Pool',
                            width : '20%',  
                            list : true,
                            edit : false,
                            sorting:true,
                            create : false,
                            display:function(data){
                               return data.record.myPool.myPoolName;
                            }

                        }
                 }
   });

  j('#infoTableId').jtable('load');
```

Comment: Please provide a JsFiddle.

Comment: If you just use this plugin for sorting  a table a invite you to take a look at : http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: Please show your server side code. You have to manage sorting at server side.

Answer (score 0):

Without code, all I can guess is that jTable field name differs from database column name.

There are many possibilities. In your case, as you are using *display function* to show the data, it should be enough if you declare the name column exactly as the database column

And if this field depends on the joining of other table, you should put *'tableName.columnName'*, with the quotes.

I use it for Spring, and the pretty solution should be calling the variables of the form which store the data(and display in the table) the same as the columns table in database.

If you do this last option, you don't need to use display function.

EDIT: After reading again I have a question. The table display any record in the first request? If the answer is No (and it display an error message), in your table declaration put the variable *defaultSorting: 'columnName'* after your *sorting: true*.

Answer (score 0):

Brother, you just have to add this in your query at the listing page.

```
if($_GET["jtSorting"]!=null &&$_GET["jtSorting"]!="")
{
$query_s =$query_s. " ORDER BY ".$_GET["jtSorting"]." ";
}
```

Use this after your WHERE clause and before LIMIT condition. 
hope this will work, 
also "MyId"  and "myPoolName"  must match the field names in DB.  title doesn't matter. Hope this will work

Comment: i know this is very late. but I hope this will help someone's else.